# WebFlux Controllers Returning Flux and Backpressure

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

In **Spring WebFlux** I have a controller similar to this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class DataController {

  @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Flux<Data> getData() {
    return <data from database using reactive driver>
  } 
}
```

1. **What exactly is subscribing to the publisher?**
2. **What (if anything) is providing backpressure?**

For context I'm trying to evaluate if there are advantages to using **Spring WebFlux** in this specific situation over **Spring MVC**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I am not a developer of spring framework, so any comments are welcome.

> What exactly is subscribing to the publisher?

It is a long living subscription to the port (the server initialisation itself). Therefore, the `ReactorHttpServer.class` has the method:

```
@Override
protected void startInternal() {
    DisposableServer server = this.reactorServer.handle(this.reactorHandler).bind().block();
    setPort(((InetSocketAddress) server.address()).getPort());
    this.serverRef.set(server);
}
```

The `Subscriber` is the bind method, which (as far as I can see) does `request(Long.MAX_VALUE)`, so no back pressure management here.

The important part for request handling is the method `handle(this.reactorHandler)`. The `reactorHandler` is an instance of `ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter`. Further up the stack (within the `apply` method of `ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter`) is the `DispatcherHandler.class`. The java doc of this class starts with " Central dispatcher for HTTP request handlers/controllers. Dispatches to registered handlers for processing a request, providing convenient mapping facilities.". It has the central method:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    if (this.handlerMappings == null) {
        return createNotFoundError();
    }
    return Flux.fromIterable(this.handlerMappings)
            .concatMap(mapping -> mapping.getHandler(exchange))
            .next()
            .switchIfEmpty(createNotFoundError())
            .flatMap(handler -> invokeHandler(exchange, handler))
            .flatMap(result -> handleResult(exchange, result));
}
```

Here, the actual request processing happens. The response is written within `handleResult`. It now depends on the actual server implementation, how the result is written.

For the default server, i.e. Reactor Netty it will be a `ReactorServerHttpResponse.class`. Here you can see the method `writeWithInternal`. This one takes the `publisher` result of the handler method and writes it to the underlying HTTP connection:

```
@Override
protected Mono<Void> writeWithInternal(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> publisher) {
    return this.response.send(toByteBufs(publisher)).then();
}
```

One implementation of `NettyOutbound.send( ... )` is `reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations`. For your specific case of a Flux return, this implementation manages the NIO within `MonoSendMany.class`. This class does `subscribe( ... )` with a `SendManyInner.class`, which does back pressure management by implementing `Subscriber` which `onSubscribe` does `request(128)`. I guess Netty internally uses TCP ACK to signal successful transmission.

So,

> What (if anything) is providing backpressure?

... yes, backpressure is provided, e.g. by `SendManyInner.class`, however also other implementations exist.

> For context I'm trying to evaluate if there are advantages to using Spring WebFlux in this specific situation over Spring MVC.

I think, it is definitely worth evaluating. For performance I however guess, the result will depend on the amount of concurrent requests and maybe also on the type of your `Data` class. Generally speaking, Webflux is usually the preferred choice for high throughput, low latency situations, and we generally see better hardware utilization in our environments. Assuming you take your data from a database you probably will have the best results with a database driver that too supports reactive. Besides performance, the back pressure management is always a good reason to have a look at Webflux. Since we adopted to Webflux, our data platform never had problems with stability anymore (not to claim, there are no other ways to have a stable system, but here many issues are solved out of the box).

As a side note: I recommend, having a closer look at `Schedulers` we just recently gained 30% cpu time by choosing the right one for slow DB accesses.

**EDIT:**
In https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-handler-functions the reference documentation explicitly says:

> ServerRequest and ServerResponse are immutable interfaces that offer JDK 8-friendly access to the HTTP request and response. Both request and response provide Reactive Streams back pressure against the body streams.

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly is subscribing to the publisher?

The framework (so Spring, in this case.)

In general, you shouldn't subscribe in your own application - the framework should be subscribing to your publisher when necessary. In the context of spring, that's whenever a relevant request hits that controller.

> What (if anything) is providing backpressure?

In this case, it's only restricted by the speed of the connection (I believe Webflux will look at the underlying TCP layer) and then request data as required. Whether your upstream flux *listens* to that backpressure though is another story - it may do, or it may just flood the consumer with as much data as it can.

> For context I'm trying to evaluate if there are advantages to using Spring WebFlux in this specific situation over Spring MVC.

The main advantage is being able to hold huge numbers of connections open with only a few threads - so no overhead of context switching. (That's not the *sole* advantage, but most of the advantages generally boil down to that point.) Usually, this is only an advantage worth considering if you need to hold in the region of thousands of connections open at once.

The main disadvantage is the fact reactive code looks *very* different from standard Java code, and is usually necessarily more complex as a result. Debugging is also harder - vanilla stack traces become all but useless for instance (though their are tools & techniques to make this easier.)